# Woocommerce price_excluding_tax is same as price_including_tax

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, price, tax

I have enabled tax rates and calculations. I'm entering prices inclusive of tax. The standard tax rate is set to 20% but the price_excluding_tax is the same as price_including_tax.

Can you tell me, if there is something in the settings which I have to change, or what else could be the problem?